# October CMS: refreshing field values?

Tags: octobercms

In my plugin when I edit and save an item some field values are not refreshed.
For instance, the "updated_at" field still shows the old DateTime value even though it has been updated in the database.
How can I refresh specific field values?
Should I use partials or is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

When using an AJAX handler in your FormController, you can update a single field in your form using this:

```
public function onYourAjaxHandler($recordID)
{
    $model = MyModel::findOrFail($recordID);
    $model->fieldToUpdate = "new value";
    $this->initForm($model);

    $fieldMarkup = $this->formGetWidget()->renderField('fieldToUpdate', ['useContainer' => true]);

    return [
      '#field-id' => $fieldMarkup
    ];
}
```

If you need to replace the field container, set useContainer => false. If you need to keep the container, set useContainer => true.

Since v452 of OctoberCMS, it is now possible to use the formRenderField() method directly as the "options" argument has been added to it:

```
    $this->formRenderField('fieldToUpdate', ['useContainer'=>false])
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use the `update_onSave()` function in my controller but I get this error: `Call to a member function renderField() on null` 
Regarding the other option should I put the `$this->formRenderField()` code line in a partial or elsewhere ?

Comment: Are you using the FormController behavior in your controller?

Comment: Yes, but if I put the `formRenderField` code in my `update_onSave()` function I get an error: `Call to a member function renderField() on null`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm you need to set `certain attributes/variables` of your model to `achieve` that.

```
class YourModel extends Model
{   
    // set this to true
    public $timestamps = true;   
}
```

> $timestamps: if `true` will `automatically` set **created_at** and **updated_at** fields. ( make sure your table has this same exact column names **created_at** and **updated_at** )

check reference : https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model#standard-properties

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: Thanks but I think you got me wrong.  
The updated_at field is properly set when saving, the thing is the field is not refreshed and I have to press the F5 key of the browser to display the new value.  
This problem is discussed [here](https://octobercms.com/forum/post/form-aftersave-refresh)   
but the explanation is quite confusing and I'm not sure the proposed solution is correct.   

Any idea ?

Comment: oh i see I skipped `it has been updated in the database` this line, ok let me check if there is any better solution